# JQuery slidetoggle div with javascript link in header wont fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a simple collapsible div (content) that expands or collapses when the user clicks in another div (the header).

I also have an anchor tag that calls a javascript function in the header div.

However, when i click the link, instead of the javascript firing, the content div expands or collapses.

How do I make it so that if the user clicks the link the javascript fires, but if the user clicks any where else in the header, the content expands or collapses?

I'm sure its very simple, but haven't had much exposure to JQuery.

Thanks.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

<title></title>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .container
    {
        width: 600px;
    }
    .content
    {
        display:            none;
        padding:            10px;
        border-top:         1px;
        border-top-color:   #cccccc;
        border-top-style:   solid;
        border-left:        1px;
        border-left-color:  #999999;
        border-left-style:  solid;
        border-right:       1px;
        border-right-color: #999999;
        border-right-style: solid;
    }
    .header
    {
        height:             30px;
        color:              #336699;
        padding-left:       10px;
        padding-top:        5px;
        padding-bottom:     5px;
        background-color:   #f8f8f8;
        border-top:         1px;
        border-top-color:   #999999;
        border-top-style:   solid;
        border-left:        1px;
        border-left-color:  #999999;
        border-left-style:  solid;
        border-right:       1px;
        border-right-color: #999999;
        border-right-style: solid;
    }
    .headerContentTitle 
    {
        width:              480px;
        float:              left;
    }
    .headerContentLink 
    {
        width:              80px;
        float:              left;
    }
    .headerContentIcon 
    {
        float:              left;
    }
    .footer
    {
        border-bottom:          1px;
        border-bottom-color:    #999999;
        border-bottom-style:    solid;
        margin-bottom:          5px;
    }

</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[

    $(window).load(function () {
        function slide() {
            $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle("fast");

            var $img = $(this).find(".expImage");
            if ($img.attr("src") == "/Images/Expand.png") {
                $img.attr("src", "/Images/Collapse.png");
            }
            else {
                $img.attr("src", "/Images/Expand.png");
            }
            return false;
        }
        //$(".header").click(slide);
    });

    //]]>  
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function SelectAllClicked(HeaderID)
    {
        alert(HeaderID);
    }

</script>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headerContent">
            <div class="headerContentTitle">This is the first header</div>
            <div class="headerContentLink"><a href="javascript:SelectAllClicked('Header Value')">Select all</a></div>
            <div class="headerContentIcon"><img class="expImage" src="/Images/Expand.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">This is the first content</div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this, It will work :)


<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".header").click(function(e){
                if(e.target.nodeName != 'A'){
                $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle("fast");

                var $img = $(this).find(".expImage");
                if ($img.attr("src") == "/Images/Expand.png") {
                    $img.attr("src", "/Images/Collapse.png");
                }
                else {
                    $img.attr("src", "/Images/Expand.png");
                }
                return false;           
            }
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified "CreativeDeep's" answer

```
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".header").click(function(e){
                if(e.target.nodeName != 'A'){
                $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle("fast");
            }
        });
    });
    //]]>
```